# win 7 Batch File - NTFS permissions

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, permissions, command-prompt

Im looking for some help on a batch file for managing NTFS permissions through a batch file.

I have created a folder containing several subfolders. The main folder is shared through NET SHARE command and is working. Now I need to set NTFS permission through command-line commands in batch file.

I need to remove access for any users except admin and a specific user.

i can add the specific user through `ICACLS C:\bruger2\jesper /grant:r jesper:f`

but the remove part wont work

`ICACLS c:\bruger2\jesper /remove Users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm guys, I found the answer.

I needed to include **/inheritance:r** to remove inherited NTFS permissions

```
ICACLS C:\bruger\jesper /inheritance:r /grant:r jesper:f Holms:f
```